# C++, vectors, pointers and objects confusion

Tags: c++

I am working on a project as a homework for my university course of Systems Programming.
I got really confused with the matter of Pointers, Vectors, stacks and heaps.

Using C++.
I have to get a vector of objects which are courses, and those courses objects have several different fields.
What I did was this:

```
vector<CoursesObject> coursevector;
```

and then I created my Courses Object class, which contains the space left in course and name of course fields.
Now I want to add a new course, I do:

```
CoursesObject *theCourse = new CoursesObject(name, space);
```

now I want to add it to the handler vector:

```
coursevector.push_back(*theCourse);
```

With all I know, I created a vector of Courses objects on the stack, and made a new pointer to a new course that is on the heap, and added to the handler vector the pointer theCourse that points to the course object in the heap. Is what I said correct?

When I try to delete those course objects, I do:

```
for(int i=0; i<coursevector.size(); i++)
    delete coursevector.at(i);
```

which gives me an error that it is not a pointer. But haven't I added to the coursevector a POINTER to the course object?

Please somebody explain, I have to handle the memory correctly and it seems that I am not getting it right.

Comment: You can use vector<* CoursesObject> and use it store pointers instead of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to use new at all.

```
//This vector stores CoursesObject objects,
//not pointers to CoursesObjects.
vector<CoursesObject> coursevector;
//Construct theCourse with automatic storage
//duration.
CoursesObject theCourse(name, space);
//Copy theCourse into coursevector
coursevector.push_back(theCourse);
//theCourse will be automatically destroyed.
//coursevector (and all the objects that it contains)
//will be automatically destroyed.
```

Answer (score 5):

This

```
vector<CoursesObject> coursevector;
```

is a vector of `CourseObjects`, so it cannot hold `CourseObject` pointers. When you do this:

```
coursevector.push_back(*theCourse);
```

you get a copy of the `CoursesObject` pointed at by `theCourse` stored in the vector. You do not need to delete any entries from the vector. In fact, you can't, because it doesn't hold pointers.

You program would be much simpler if you just avoided the dynamic allocation:

```
coursevector.push_back(CoursesObject(name, space));
```

Comment: so the object ITSELF (not the pointer to it) gets stored in the handler vector?
And also, this way, I only need to delete the pointer theCourse, right?

Comment: @user1656647 A **copy** of the object itself gets stored. So yes, you only need to delete the original, but I don't think there is a reason to allocate it dynamically in the first place.

Comment: great. then this just leaves me with the question on HOW to delete the course object itself from the heap?

Comment: Just `delete theCourse` after insertion to the vector, or better still, do not allocate it dynamically (see my last edit).

Comment: Great.
then now, the handler vector coursevector gets deleted automatically, because it was not allocated dynamically. right?

Comment: That's right - it will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @user That's the point. You don't. You aren't supposed to create the course object on the heap in the first place. If you do it like juan said in the last line, the CoursesObjects in your vector will be automatically destroyed once the vector goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

all of your objects are not dynamically allocated, so you cannot delete them at any time during the program. Remember that you can only delete object once they are dynamically allocated:

```
int Var1 = 0;  //cannot be deleted, scope and life will exist for the life of program
int * Var2 = new int; //CAN be deleted, dynamically allocated.

delete Var2; //free memory
```

You can however delete your last object, which is a pointer. I would grab the last element of the vector and call delete on it(which should be your pointer to the class).

Comment: so, the course object with the name and space, where does it sit? in the heap or the stack? because I did it as new CoursesObject(name, space)...

Comment: I'm not quite following, but simply changing your courseobject to courseobject* would allow you to delete variables, considering you add pointers to the vector in place of just normal objects this time around.

Answer (score 0):

when you do this:

```
coursevector.push_back(*theCourse);
```

actually you are dereferencing the pointer theCourse, so you are adding a copy of the object. You need to declare a vector of CourseObject pointers:

```
vector<CoursesObject *> coursevector;
```

Then you add an object:

```
coursevector.push_back(theCourse);
```

Now your code to delete the objects should work:

```
for(int i=0; i<coursevector.size(); i++)
    delete coursevector.at(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

`coursevector` can hold only `CoursesObject`s and not pointers to `CoursesObject`s, so you needn't use the `new` operator (check @Mankarse's answer). But, if you still want to hold pointers, then change the definition of coursevector to

```
vector<CoursesObject*> coursevector;
```

and push_back the value of the pointer as it is:

```
coursevector.push_back(theCourse);
```